# Why was the plane empty in The Impossible

Tags: plot-explanation, the-impossible

As part of the final scene of the 2012 drama The Impossible, we can observe that the plane that was picking up the injured family has plenty of empty seats and no one else on board aside from some personnel. Given the situation and many people desperately requiring medical help at the airport, why wasn’t anyone else put on board?

Comment: Because this is likely paid by their insurance etc.

Comment: Indeed, the plane was provided by Zurich Insurance who would not take on anyone who was not their client.

Answer (score 3):

Because it was a private plane (deigned for medical transports) that was chartered by the insurance of the injured family, Zurich Insurance. And as such it was only available to their clients.

Arguably, that final scene is another one that hammers home the vast gap between the Thai population and the Westerners: this family can get on this plane and leave the devastation behind and get "proper" medical care in Singapore (and don't share this privilege with other victims), whereas previously in the movie the locals are shown over and over again to share what few resources they have left with anyone needing help.